# Set camera in motion within DeviceOrientationControls

Tags: javascript, three.js, device-orientation

I am creating a webVR app with Three.js. I have implemented DeviceOrientationControls, but now would like to move around in the virtual space with the magnet button on the google cardboard.

I want it so one click from the magnet will set the camera in motion in whatever direction I am looking. Another click will stop the motion.

Is this possible? If so, how could I implement this, I am completely stuck.
My assumption is the magnet causes a "click" event. But after detecting this click, how do I make the camera move around in the direction I am looking?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `DeviceOrientationControls`'s `freeze` property:

```
var controls = new THREE.DeviceOrientationControls(camera);
controls.connect();
controls.update();

window.addEventListener('click', function() { controls.freeze = !controls.freeze; }, false);
```

This of course will only work if you have a version of Google Cardboard that makes contact with the screen. Original Cardboards with magnetic field-only switches will be inaccessible as there is no exposed magnetometer API (unless, say, your device has a poor quality rotation sensor in which using `DeviceOrientationControls` is a bad idea in the first place).

Comment: Thanks. I don't have a version where the button actually touches the screen to create the "click", but I don't think I have any other choice. I'll probably have to rig something up within the cardboard to touch the screen.